# A GridView inside a Wizard in wicket fails to render error feedback messages

Tags: wicket

I have a custom Wizard, defined as follows:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div>
        <form wicket:id="form" class="wizard">
            <span class="wizardoverview" wicket:id="overview"/>

            <div class="wizardheader" wicket:id="header"/>
            <div wicket:id="view" class="wizardpage"/>
            <span wicket:id="feedback"/>

            <div class="buttons">
                <span wicket:id="buttons"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

The wizardpage is in this case a Panel with its own form.
This form contains a new Panel, which in turn contains a GridView.
The GridView contains a set of Panels, which each contain a FormComponentFeedbackBorder, which in turn contains input TextFields.

Phew!

So we have this:

Wizard->WizardpagePanel->Form->GridContainingPanel->GridView->Panel[]->FormComponentFeedbackBorder->TextField

When TextField fails validation, no feedback is rendered at all.
If I add a FeedbackPanel to the GridContainingPanel the error messages are rendered, but FormComponentFeedbackBorder renders nothing.

Any pointers as to what can be wrong?

I had a similar problem with a ListView instead of GridView, but that problem was resolved when I set listView.setReuseItems(true);

Is there a similar setting for GridView, or is there a different solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to go deeper :) No, seriously, all I can think of is that GridView has its own `setItemReuseStrategy`-method.

Comment: That was it:        gridView.setItemReuseStrategy(new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy()); solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it:

```
gridView.setItemReuseStrategy(new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy());
```

solved the problem.

Thanks, rotsch.