# Wicket: Validating nested forms inside DataTable component

Tags: forms, wicket

I'm currently testing the creation of a custom DataTable where I need to have a a panel with a form inside some of the table cells, with the following structure:

Outer form > DataTable (rows > cells > cell > panel > inner form)

At the moment, I am able to successfully submit these nested forms (inner forms inside each cell) with the submit button of an outer form, but the inner forms do not show the validation feedback messages (although I checked and they are being validated - the outer form goes to onError() on validation error).

I believe this problem is somehow related to the similar issue with ListView where I have to use setReuseItems(true) in order to be able to get the feedback messages. (Ref: [wicket validate textfield inside listview can't see error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930999/wicket-validate-textfield-inside-listview-cant-see-error-messages))

I have tried to configure the DataTable reuse item strategy, and even the DataTable inner datagrid (as from Wicket 6) reuse strategy, but still, I could not get the feedback messages. (Ref:
[A GridView inside a Wizard in wicket fails to render error feedback messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080935/a-gridview-inside-a-wizard-in-wicket-fails-to-render-error-feedback-messages))

I'm starting to think that I might not be able to this at the DataTable level, since the onPopulate() of the cells is really only called on the AbstractDataGridView level. Does anyone know then if validating these inner forms inside of a DataTable is possible and, if so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Have you tried to add the inner form to the feedbackpanel filters? with: feedback.setFilter(new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(innerform));

Comment: No such luck with setFilter. Thanks for the comment, anyway.

Comment: In case anyone has a similar problem, I ended up creating a new 'CustomDataTable' component based on the ListView. That way, I was able to use the setReuseItems(true).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the way I solved it was like this:

```
Form<List<MyDataType>> form = new Form<List<MyDataType>>("form", getModel()) {
    @Override
    protected void onValidate() {
        super.onValidate();
        visitChildren(FormComponent.class, new IVisitor<FormComponent, Void>() {
            @Override
            public void component(FormComponent component, IVisit<Void> visit) {
                component.processInput();
                if (component.hasErrorMessage()) {
                    for (FeedbackMessage message :
                         component.getFeedbackMessages()) {
                        if (message.isError()) {
                            get(TABLE_ID).getFeedbackMessages().add(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

So basically when ever I validate my `Form`, I manually check for inner `FormComponent`s and check those. Then I forward the error messages to the table which has its own `FeedbackPanel`.

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

table.setItemReuseStrategy(new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy()) set the trick for me

source:

## 1 [wicket validate textfield inside listview can't see error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930999/wicket-validate-textfield-inside-listview-cant-see-error-message?lq=1)

## 2 [A GridView inside a Wizard in wicket fails to render error feedback messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080935/a-gridview-inside-a-wizard-in-wicket-fails-to-render-error-feedback-messages?rq=1)